# Establishing a hypothesis involving three measures

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I have 50 Training instances. A training instance is a particular simulation with specific parameters. I have 30 different policies. When I run the experiment with one training instance and one policy I get 3 measures. I wish to determine how the three measures are related to each other. I have a hypothesis that if value of measure 2 is higher for one policy, then value of measure 3 is also higher. I also have a hypothesis that measure 1 is independent of the other two.  Assuming I run the 1500 experiments, how do I test my hypothesis?

Comment: "measure 2 is high, then measure 3 is high" seems a bit too vague for answering

Comment: @peuhp hope its more clear